# Python Compare and Update CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files.

csv_1 columns:

```
AP Name       Mac           Switch      Port
AP-2-2    001122334455   switchname1    0/37
AP-2-3    554433221100   switchname2    0/41
```

csv_2 columns:

```
    Mac         Switch      Port
001122334455   switchname1  0/37
554433221100   switchname2  0/41
```

I want to update the switch and port columns in `csv_1` with the switch and port in `csv_2` based on when a mac address match found (these are not in order).

What is the best and most efficient way to do this properly in python? I know how to read in the CSV files, I'm just not sure how to check the values properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas to join in the new values:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("<path to csv1>.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("<path to csv2>.csv").rename(columns={"Switch": "new_switch", "Port": "new_port"})

# clean up column names
df1.columns = [i.strip() for i in df1.columns]
df2.columns = [i.strip() for i in df2.columns]

# join in new values
result = df1.join(df2.set_index("Mac"), on="Mac")

# use the new values where they're defined, otherwise fill in with the old values
result["Switch"] = result["new_switch"].fillna(result["Switch"])
result["Port"] = result["new_port"].fillna(result["Port"])

# delete the "new" columns, which are no longer needed
del result["new_switch"], result["new_port"]

# write out
result.to_csv("<path to new csv>.csv", index=False)
```

This assumes your csv2 has only one row for each `Mac` value.

Comment: I get a ```KeyError: 'Mac'``` - Any thoughts on that?

Comment: What prints out when you run `df2.columns`? There's likely some trailing whitespace in your column names. See updated answer for some code to strip that out

Comment: Yea I had some weird stuff when I printed out df2.columns but I got it sorted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided specific code examples, I'm assuming you have already parsed the csv file and would like help with the processing. Try something like this:

```
for index_2, row_2 in enumerate(csv_2):
    for index_1, row_1 in enumerate(csv_1):
        if row_2.mac == row_1.mac:
            csv_1[index_1].switch = csv_2[index_2].switch
            csv_1[index_1].port = csv_2[index_2].port
```

Then, write csv_1 back out to the file.